# Distribution of points with essentially different hierarchical clusterings

Tags: cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

An algorithm for hierarchically clustering points in a given metric space is essentially determined by the [linkage criterion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering#Linkage_criteria) it uses.

When performing an agglomerative clustering (with each point in its own cluster at the beginning) the metric defines the distance between singleton clusters (in the first step), and the linkage criterion defines the distance between arbitrary clusters (in  further steps).

The [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering#Example_for_Agglomerative_Clustering) exhibits an easy to grasp example (of "points" in two-dimensional Euclidean space **R**<sup>2</sup>). But all the linkage criteria which are [proposed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering#Linkage_criteria) seem to provide the same hierarchical clustering.

So I wonder:

> What is the **smallest** example of a distribution of points (smallest by number of points) in
>   **R**<sup>2</sup> for which each of the proposed linkage criteria yields a different result?

Answer (score 1):

Do the points need to be disjoint?

You may want to fiddle around with *1 dimensional integer numbers* first.

```
1 2 3 4
```

for example will already cluster differently with single-linkage, complete-linkage, and probably others.
Try a fibonacci sequence, or prime numbers...

Comment: Yes, points should be disjoint. And the idea of playing around in 1D with natural numbers is a good one!

Comment: Being disjoint doesn't gain you much I believe - often you can produce a similar effect by having objects at the exact same distance to each other, as in this integer case. In a two dimensional setting, one could use e.g. `(0,0) (0,1) (0,-1) (100,0) (100,1)` to force clusters of different cardinality (which causes UPGMA/WPGMA to produce different results, for example).